# How to fix Sublime Text PPA in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, ppa, sublime-text

```bsh
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                                    
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                                  
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:5 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease                                                                                   
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                                     
Hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease                                                          
Hit:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease     
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/peek-developers/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-2/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-2/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-2/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Whenever I try to do `sudo apt update` it gives me this error and exits, I don't remember the way in which I installed sublime text throught terminal as it was 2 weeks ago, is there a way to solve this

I followed this tutorial to download sublime text from this heading
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/582849/installingplussublimeplustextplus2plusonpluslinuxp

> Installing Sublime Text on Linux Mint /Ubuntu– The Better Method

I also tried uninstalling it but that didn't work

```bsh
$ sudo snap remove sublime-text
sublime-text removed
```

`

Comment: The PPA in your error messages provides support up to *bionic* or 18.04; you're on 20.04 so normal checks should have shown it doesn't support *focal* or 20.04 (PPA's are 3rd party sources so all checks are on you; a PPA that had support end in  2018 cannot provide support for a 2020-April release).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Remove the outdated PPA

The webupd8 PPA has not been updated since 2018, and does not support Ubuntu 20.04.

Remove it with

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
```

### Install Sublime Text 4 from its official repository

The instructions for Installing sublime text can be found at [its website](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/linux_repositories.html).

First, install the GPG key:

```
wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then enable https sources in apt

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
```

For the stable version, enter the command

```
echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list
```

Update apt index and install Sublime Text

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install sublime-text
```

Comment: I get this Err:17 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Release                                                          
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 104.236.0.104 443]

Comment: @AlexSeif Please ask a new question

Comment: Thank you @archisman-panigrahi, I don't think I will get a good answer, the issue is with sublime repo I guess